# How to retrieve specific line using Spark and JavaRDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I used below code for retrieve data from text file. There is used specific key word (Error) for retrieve data.

```
        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = input.map(RowFactory::create);
        List<StructField> fields = Arrays.asList(
          DataTypes.createStructField("error_msg", DataTypes.StringType, true));
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

        DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

        Column column = new Column("error_msg");

        DataFrame errors = df.filter(column.like("%Error%"));
        System.out.println(errors.showString(1));
```

After executing above code, output is follows

```
+--------------------+
|           error_msg|
+--------------------+
|java.lang.OutOfMe...|
+--------------------+
```

I want to remove all those '+' and '-' marks and get only the message line (java.lang.OutOfMe...). And also there haven't display whole line in output. 
Is there any methods or workarounds for solve this issue. Any help can be really appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution. When using the errors.first(), can get the whole error line.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `errors.first()`, can get the whole identified line and split it in your way.